# "npm install" shows multiple errors (node-sass, node.exe, python2, python...)

Tags: npm, npm-install

Currently I have error when running "npm install". I seriously have no clue what is the problem, so I am truly appreciate if someone could help me.

My environment is Win 10

Node version 16.13.0

NPM version 8.1.0

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much time of searching for the solution, it turned out to be very simple. I downgraded my node version to 14.15.1 and it worked!